# Can the full name and profile picture of a user signed in via Facebook API be displayed publicly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Rephrased, is it possible to use the Facebook Open Graph API to display a user's full name and profile picture to other site members who are not Facebook friends with the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; users' first name, last name and profile picture are publicly available. You can retrieve them from the Graph API (along with other information they have made available) by calling:

https://graph.facebook.com/[user_id_or_name]

This will return a JSON string containing the relevant information.

Enjoy! :)