# Displaying list of users of a facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Am working on a facebook application and i will like to display to the user his/her friends that are already users of the application.

I have been able to get the facebook user ids of the users. Now am trying to find out if there is a facebook api resource i can use to render the user's pictures and names by just passing the ids to it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should try out with FQL and the user table.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

There you have a is_app_user field, which can be queried. The table is indexed by uid, which means you can use ids of friends to check.

With fql like this you should be able to read all friend ids who are using your app, assuming $user is current user id:

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = 1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $user)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, i already have the user ids of the user's friend using my applications. If you refer to my question, you will see I state that clearly. What i want to be able to do is to have the users displayed in facebook's standard way. Thanks

Comment: Ooops, sorry. But FQL IS standard way. Please read users table documentation and alter fql to return uid, name and picture or whatever you need.

Comment: Or you should exactly provide information about what you think we should understand with "to be able to do is to have the users displayed in facebook's standard way". In "displaying" something  there are no standards. The anwser would be HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. what i have been trying to avoid is to format and display the users with HTML and CSS. Used to think there is a facebook reasource i can just pass the user ids to and it will take care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this post: [Can the full name and profile picture of a user signed in via Facebook API be displayed publicly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451248/can-the-full-name-and-profile-picture-of-a-user-signed-in-via-facebook-api-be-dis/4451628#4451628)

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I already have the user ids, i can get the picture and names, but my challenge is rendering such information in facebook's standard way, like the way you call the fb:multi-friend-selector that then displays a block of your friends. So am trying to figure out if there is suck library for displaying some users which you have their ids.

Comment: I know it's an ugly workaround, but you could specify the uids of all the users friends *except the ones you have selected*, in the "exclude_ids" parameter of the fb:multi-friend-selector?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can use FQL to get the information you need. But if you just want to use the user ID, you can use FBML and have the Facebook javascript lib render the FBML on the client side. You would want to use fb:name and fb:profile-pic then.

You could also use fb:multi-friend-selector if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to specify the users you want fb:multi-friend-selector to show by specifying their ids? what i have been trying to avoid is to format and display the users with HTML and CSS. Used to think there is a facebook reasource i can just pass the user ids to and it will take care of the rest

Comment: Sort of. You can pass IDs to exclude, not include. FBML is the only way to do it if you don't want to do the HTML and CSS yourself. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this documentation page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/#user/groups.

Use the `fb:name` tag for the name and `fb:profile-pic` for the profile picture.

Just loop through all the IDs and display the those two tags for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for it's the [Facebook facepile](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/), it's a social plugin.
Just give the app_id and it shows the faces of your friends using it.